# notifyDataSetChanged() not working in daimajia AndroidSwipeLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use AndroidSwipeLayout (https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) in my project . Everything is working fine and it meet my requirement .

Issue is that when I try to filter the list view I am not able to updated the data set .

There is an open issue https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/issues/258 for the same problem for which I have mentioned

Can any one please provide me a work around for this issue

Or any alternative library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less than ideal work around : 
Alternative would be to reset the adapter with the filtered list.

Suppose you have your list in the adapter, maintain a copy to filter the items in list. Reset the adapter with the filtered list.

Pseudo code :

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> originalList;
ArrayList<CustomObject> filteredList;

filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
filteredList.addAll(originalList);

setAdapter(filteredList); //Sets the adapter with filtered List.

//In your searchView implementation

private void onSearchQuery(String searchString) {
   if( searchString == null || searchString.trim().length() == 0 ) {
     filteredList.clear();
     filteredList.addAll(originalList);
     //Since adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is not working.
     setAdapter(filteredList); //Sets the adapter with filtered List.
   }
   else {
     filteredList.clear();
     for( CustomObject customObject : originalList ) {
        if( customObject.getSearchableField().contains(searchString) ) {
           filteredList.add(customObject);
        }
     }
     //Since adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is not working.
     setAdapter(filteredList); //Sets the adapter with filtered List.
   }
}
```